# Unable to make Firebase push notification works in WebView

Tags: android, firebase, webview, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I followed the following tutorial to create an HTML page and the service worker to receive Firebase web push notification
https://www.itwonders-web.com/blog/push-notification-using-firebase-demo-tutorial

I host my own page in a https server. It works on Chrome & Firefox desktop browsers and I can get the toekn and receive the push notification. However, when I tried to load the same page in a WebView, it doesn't work. I've enabled DOM storage and JavaScript.

The error log shows

> I/chromium(22193): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser).", source: https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.1/firebase-app.js (1)

For loading the WebView, I use Flutter with [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package. The webview version is 87.0.4280.141. Below is the log from nginx

> "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; Redmi Note 8 Pro Build/QP1A.190711.020; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Mobile Safari/537.36"

Looking from [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/push-api), the version 87 supports push API. Why it doesn't work? Is it possible to receive Firebase web push notification in a WebView? Because I have a case where I only have control to modify the pages displayed using WebView, so I cannot receive the push notification in the native app.

Comment: Chromium uses Safari's web view here as you can see in your last log: "Mobile Safari/537.36". Mobile Safari does not support the Web Push standard that is required for receiving FCM messages, as per the same caniuse link that you shared.

Comment: Why does it use Safari's web view? My phone is running Android 10